# Tika 1.7 integration to Solr 5.1.0

Tags: parsing, solr, rss, feed, apache-tika

I want to parse (many) rss/atom/rdf feeds using Tika 1.7 (works pretty well but not perfect) and upload data into Solr 5.1.0. automatically.

I can see the data in my terminal - looks pretty nice, each item parsed: title, link, description etc - but I don't know how to load data automatically into Solr.

Any help is welcome,
Kind regards,
Christian

Answer (score 1):

There's a contrib module called "SolrCell" which is a content extraction library. That works exactly as you want, and it uses Tika behind the scenes, for text and metadata extraction.

More information here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Solr+Cell+using+Apache+Tika

Comment: Hi, thing is that it seems to me that the "SolrCell" only parse PDF & HTML files. I need to parse feed files (rss/atom/rdf and other xml-type files) and it doesn't seem to work... I managed to seed the parse output in the terminal in Tika 1.8 but I need to capture the output ... maybe in an xml file that I cand later upload in Solr using curl... please advise

Comment: SolrCell does what Tika does. Although I don't remember the whole list of supported formats, it is not limited to those 2....there are a lot more

Comment: if anyone can show me how to upload rss/atom/rdf feeds into solr using SolrCell - which I have tried but failed - it would be great! Please help!